# PHP, MYSQL: Order by date but empty dates last not first

Tags: php, mysql, date, fetch

I fetch an array with todo titles and due dates from MySQL. I want to order it by date and have the oldest on top. But there are some todos without a date. These todos I don't want to show at first positions but rather at the bottom of my list. Unfortunately MySQL put the empty ones first.

Is there any way I can do it *in one query* (can't use MySQLi, using CI's ActiveRecord). I could run a second query for all todos without dates and put them at the bottom. But I'd like to make it in one query – if possible?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do it in MySQL with the `ORDER BY` clause. Sort by `NULL` first, then the date.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY (date_column IS NULL), date_column ASC
```

**Note:** This assumes rows without a date are `NULL`.

Comment: Cool :-) Works fine! I have to change the empty ones to NULL instead of 0000-00-00 but then it is exactly what I need.

Comment: Good. Yes, `NULL` is a much better representation for row without a date than `0000-00-00`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
  ORDER BY  CASE your_date 
              WHEN '' THEN 'b' 
              ELSE 'a' 
            END,
            date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

possibly add a `NVL( thedate, to_date('2099-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd'))` in the order by clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
select * from my_table
order by if(isnull(my_field),1,0),my_field;
```

Comment: Why the use of `isnull()` *and* `if()`

Answer (score -1):

Well, as a pure MySQL answer, I would probably do it like this.

```
  select todo.title, todo.due_date
    from todo
    order by ifnull(todo.due_date, '9999-12-31')
```